# Django - stop form text area from autopopulating

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am making a login form with Django, but after I add a password input widget to my loginForm, the form text autopopulates with the first user in my database (See image below). This happens after I refresh or submit the form. I want the username and password fields to  be blank.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fFTK.png)

forms.py:

```
class loginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

views.py:

```
def loginview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            return HttpResponse('<html> Thanks </html>')
        else:
            form = loginForm()
    else:
        form = loginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="" action="" method="post">
            <div class="field">
                {{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                {{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}
            </div>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Login to Your Grocerylist Account ">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not, the population happens likely by the *browser*, especially since Django does not *save* passwords, it saves the *hash* of a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by the *browser*, not by Django. This is likely why the textfield has a lightblue background. Django can not fill in the password, since Django does not *save* the password at all: it stores a *hash* of the password. So it can not recover the original password, it can only verify if the hashes of the two passwords are the same.

A browser will often store credentials, this is safer, since a user easily use different passwords for different sites. It thus makes browsing more convenient and safer for the user.

You can likely open the settings of the browser and remove the saved password. If you then refresh the page, the password will no longer be filled in.